# Large smallest $i$ with $kronecker(i,n) \ne 1$

Tags: nt.number-theory

Let $kronecker(i,n)$ denote the [kronecker symbol](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kronecker_symbol). Let $n > 1$ be squarefree integer.

Define $f(n)$ to be the smallest integer $i>0$ satisfying $kronecker(i,n) \ne 1$.

> How large $f(n)$ can be infinitely often?

If $n$ is prime, $f(n)$ is the smallest quadratic nonresidue.

Is there $n$ not rather small with $f(n) > \log^2(n)$?

Comment: The function $\chi(i) = (\frac{i}{n})$ is a nontrivial character on the group $U_n = (\mathbf Z/n\mathbf Z)^\times$, so its kernel  is a proper subgroup. If the Generalized Riemann Hypothesis for all Dirichlet $L$-functions is true then Ankeny proved there is a constant $C > 0$ such that for every proper subgroup of every $U_n$ there is a positive integer less than $C(\log n)^2$ outside the subgroup. Later Eric Bach showed under GRH that we can take $C = 2$. So if you believe GRH then for each squarefree $n>1$ some positive integer $i \leq 2(\log n)^2$ has $(\frac{i}{n}) \not= 1$.

Comment: @KConrad : is it anyhow related to Cramer's conjecture ?

Comment: @Sylvain Julien, not at all.

Comment: @KConrad Thank you. I suppose $n=2$ is exception?

Comment: @joro The actual result is that for a nontrivial character $\chi$ of modulus $m$, the least $i$ such that $\chi(i)\ne1$ is at most $2(\log m)^2$. While $m=n$ for odd $n$, the modulus is $m=4n$ if $n\equiv2\pmod4$. So, yeah, $n=2$ is an exception. Larger even $n$ are not a problem, as for them the least $i$ is just $2$.